# Position two div containers on the left and right side respectively, and each div has a gap in between

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-float, css-position

I am trying to Position two div containers on the left and right side respectively, and each div has a gap in between. I am using the following codes but could not make the second div positioned on the right side, though I have added float left & right as I followed the answer from this question [Position a div container on the right side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222523/position-a-div-container-on-the-right-side)

Here are my code snippets:

```js
var getElement = document.getElementById('rectTopNearestBooth1');
getElement.style.width = "30%";
getElement.style.height = "200px";
getElement.style.zIndex = "1";
getElement.style.position = "fixed"
getElement.style.borderStyle = "solid"
getElement.style.background = "red"
getElement.style.bottom = "0px"
  // getElement.style.marginBottom = "0%"
getElement.style.marginLeft = "10%"
getElement.style.cssFloat = "left"

var getElement2 = document.getElementById('rectTopNearestBooth2');
getElement2.style.width = "0%";
getElement2.style.height = "200px";
getElement2.style.zIndex = "1";
getElement2.style.position = "fixed"
getElement2.style.borderStyle = "solid"
getElement2.style.background = "red"
getElement2.style.bottom = "0px"
getElement2.style.cssFloat = "right"
  // getElement.style.marginBottom = "0%"
getElement2.style.marginRight = "10%"
```

```html
<div id="rectTopNearestBooth1">
  <div>
    <img id="topNearestBoothLogoIcon1" />
  </div>
  <div id="topNearestBoothName1"></div>
  <div>
    <img id="nearestBoothTimeIcon1" />
    <div id="nearestBoothTimeText1"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img id="nearestBoothDistIcon1" />
    <div id="nearestBoothDistText1"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="rectTopNearestBooth2">
  <div>
    <img id="topNearestBoothLogoIcon2" />
  </div>
  <div id="topNearestBoothName2"></div>
  <div>
    <img id="nearestBoothTimeIcon2" />
    <div id="nearestBoothTimeText2"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img id="nearestBoothDistIcon2" />
    <div id="nearestBoothDistText2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can someone please help me? Thanks!

Comment: why don't you use css for styling the html?

Comment: if you are using position: fixed then you need not float the elements

Comment: @Chris, previously I am using Javascript to style the html for some reason, but I am thinking to style it using CSS later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) your elements (e.g. as you did with `position: fixed;`) or you [float](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) them. Both at the same time is not possible.

Here is an example of **only floating** the elements (I just removed the position rules):

```js
var getElement = document.getElementById('rectTopNearestBooth1');
getElement.style.width = "30%";
getElement.style.height = "200px";
getElement.style.borderStyle = "solid"
getElement.style.background = "red"
getElement.style.marginLeft = "10%"
getElement.style.cssFloat = "left"

var getElement2 = document.getElementById('rectTopNearestBooth2');
getElement2.style.width = "30%";
getElement2.style.height = "200px";
getElement2.style.borderStyle = "solid"
getElement2.style.background = "red"
getElement2.style.cssFloat = "right"
getElement2.style.marginRight = "10%"
```

```html
<div id="rectTopNearestBooth1">
  <div>
    <img id="topNearestBoothLogoIcon1" />
  </div>
  <div id="topNearestBoothName1"></div>
  <div>
    <img id="nearestBoothTimeIcon1" />
    <div id="nearestBoothTimeText1"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img id="nearestBoothDistIcon1" />
    <div id="nearestBoothDistText1"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="rectTopNearestBooth2">
  <div>
    <img id="topNearestBoothLogoIcon2" />
  </div>
  <div id="topNearestBoothName2"></div>
  <div>
    <img id="nearestBoothTimeIcon2" />
    <div id="nearestBoothTimeText2"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img id="nearestBoothDistIcon2" />
    <div id="nearestBoothDistText2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is an example of **only position** your elements (I just removed the floating rules and set `left` and `right` respectively):

```js
var getElement = document.getElementById('rectTopNearestBooth1');
getElement.style.width = "30%";
getElement.style.height = "200px";
getElement.style.borderStyle = "solid"
getElement.style.background = "red"
getElement.style.left = "10%"
getElement.style.position = "fixed"

var getElement2 = document.getElementById('rectTopNearestBooth2');
getElement2.style.width = "30%";
getElement2.style.height = "200px";
getElement2.style.borderStyle = "solid"
getElement2.style.background = "red"
getElement2.style.position = "fixed"
getElement2.style.right = "10%"
```

```html
<div id="rectTopNearestBooth1">
  <div>
    <img id="topNearestBoothLogoIcon1" />
  </div>
  <div id="topNearestBoothName1"></div>
  <div>
    <img id="nearestBoothTimeIcon1" />
    <div id="nearestBoothTimeText1"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img id="nearestBoothDistIcon1" />
    <div id="nearestBoothDistText1"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="rectTopNearestBooth2">
  <div>
    <img id="topNearestBoothLogoIcon2" />
  </div>
  <div id="topNearestBoothName2"></div>
  <div>
    <img id="nearestBoothTimeIcon2" />
    <div id="nearestBoothTimeText2"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img id="nearestBoothDistIcon2" />
    <div id="nearestBoothDistText2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using css:

```css
div[id^="rectTopNearestBooth"] {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  height: 200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 10%;
  border: solid black;
  background: tomato;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="rectTopNearestBooth1">
  <div>
    <img id="topNearestBoothLogoIcon1" />
  </div>
  <div id="topNearestBoothName1"></div>
  <div>
    <img id="nearestBoothTimeIcon1" />
    <div id="nearestBoothTimeText1"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img id="nearestBoothDistIcon1" />
    <div id="nearestBoothDistText1"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="rectTopNearestBooth2">
  <div>
    <img id="topNearestBoothLogoIcon2" />
  </div>
  <div id="topNearestBoothName2"></div>
  <div>
    <img id="nearestBoothTimeIcon2" />
    <div id="nearestBoothTimeText2"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img id="nearestBoothDistIcon2" />
    <div id="nearestBoothDistText2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```